# how to read data from firebase rtdb with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i cant figure out how to read specifique data from db

```
dbref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
      print(databaseEvent.snapshot.value);
    });
```

this code read all the data like this

{buzzer: {Buzzer is : ON}, Ip: {IP Address is: : 192.168.43.237}, Gas: {gas_value: 759}, Led: {Led Status: : Red}, window: {Window Status: : Open}

and when i try to read it with this code it is a null check error

```
dbref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
     print(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['gas_value']);
   });
```

so any ideas how to read it singulary like Buzzer is : ON
gas_value: 759 etc ...

and thanks

Comment: From what you write above, it looks like `databaseEvent.snapshot.value["Gas"]` is what you want?  The key in the map you printed is `Gas`, not `gas_value`?

Comment: null check error

Answer (score 0):

A print method can't have a `null` as a parameter, and I believe that the value you want to print is in

```
dbref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
 print(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['Gas']['gas_value']);
});
```

Comment: its a  null check error !

Comment: What does `print(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['Gas']);` print?

Comment: nothing it tells me its an error a null safety error olz give me your email to contact with you

Answer (score 0):

Try this databaseEvent.snapshot.child('buzzer').child('Buzzer is').value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).